# Как PHP на бэке и Java Script на фронте (или его фреймоврки) обмениваются между собой данными?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, frontend, технологии

Имеется в виду в большом, серьезном проекте, где занято много людей и разработка ведется серьезно...

понятно, что бэк на каком-то этапе передает фронту информацию, а фронт, наверное, обратно, но как именно это организовано?

Специалисты, кто сталкивался, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: а чем большой проект отличается от маленького? и там и там используется одна и та же технология передачи данных.

Comment: @Jean-Claude в маленьком проекте всё не серьёзно : )

Comment: @Jean-Claude спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть API запроси
Бекенд создает  API URL и дает нужную информацию или принимает его
https://habr.com/ru/post/464261/ можете прочитать тут
и данные можете отправить и получить с помощью например ajax или axios
https://habr.com/ru/post/14246/ - ajax
https://habr.com/ru/post/521902/ - axios